# How to connect on MSSQL server running inside a Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-21.04

I am having difficulties with MSSQL server on Docker. I created the compose file and everything starts normally, but whenever I try to login, it fails.
It won't connect locally via docker exec command:

```
sudo docker exec -it <container_id> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
```

And it also fails to connect from my remote PC via DBeaver using the same credentials:

```
2021-10-20 16:13:48.22 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
2021-10-20 16:13:48.22 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.150]
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    container_name: mssql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "SА_PASSWORD=Lmnt!1991"
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
      - "TZ=Europe/Belgrade"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/opt/mssql"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4096M
    networks:
      default:

networks:
  default:
    name: pyramid
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        -
          subnet: 172.9.9.0/24
          gateway: 172.9.9.1
```

Comment: It seems you have no problem with docker itself or network connectivity. Focus your search onto the password. Did you specify the correct variable? Is the password as you defined it really set?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Yes, in the official documentation the password variable is "SA_PASSWORD". I have also found that it might be "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" but that one also doesn't work.

Comment: Just to ensure it is not the password value: Try a primitive one with no special characters. I found some characters like % surprisingly problematic. And this problem can occur server and client side...

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri They won't work since they do not meet password requirements for this version of MSSQL unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in play here:

1. Incorrect environment variables
2. Unsafe password characters

If you watch your Docker container logs you'll see useful information such as:

```
2021-10-20 23:37:51.74 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
2021-10-20 23:37:51.74 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 172.9.9.2]
```

According to [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) State 7 means:

> 7 Login is disabled, and the password is incorrect.

This is happening because you're specifying the environment variable `SA_PASSWORD` instead of `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` in your docker-compose.yaml file. As a first step, stop and delete the container (also delete the `./data` folder) and edit the YAML to be like the following:

```yaml
    environment:
      - "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Lmnt!1991"
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
      - "TZ=Europe/Belgrade"
```

Now when you login you'll see a different login error instead:

```
2021-10-20 23:42:26.11 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2021-10-20 23:42:26.11 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 172.9.9.2]
```

This seems to be happening because the `!` is a special shell character. Stop and delete the container (also delete the `./data` folder) and edit the YAML to be like the following:

```yaml
    environment:
      - "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Lmnt@1991"
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
      - "TZ=Europe/Belgrade"
```

Now when you login, using the `@` character instead of `!`, you'll connect successfully.

**NOTE WELL:** You need to delete the `./data` folder between attempts because sa password setup only happens when the container is first started. Reconfiguring the docker-compose.yaml file and simply deleting/upping the container will not reset the sa credentials, the previous configuration will be persisting inside the `./data` folder.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? I have tried everything you said and I am still getting the same error for some reason...

Comment: Yes I did. Pay attention to the **NOTE WELL**. I haven't looked more closely into where the `sa` credentials are persisted - I think it's `msdb` - but since you're just experimenting at the moment should be safe to delete everything in the `./data` folder.